# ¿Es válido hacer preguntas del tipo "¿Cómo se llama esto o como se hace esta cosa?"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Actualmente tengo una duda con respecto al tipo de preguntas que puedo realizar en el sitio.

La gran mayoría de las preguntas que hago son directamente enfocadas al código y a la solución del problema generado por el mismo, pero he visto preguntas muy interesantes que se abarcan más a la teoría, lo cual me agrada porque aprendo en ambos aspectos.

¿Puedo realizar cuestiones como las siguientes dentro de esta comunidad?

Pregunta hipotética:

> ¿Cómo se llama lo que se encuentra en la siguiente imagen?
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> ¿Cómo se puede realizar? ¿Hay alguna librería que me ayude a realizar lo que se encuentra en la imagen?

Lo que se encuentra en la imagen lo conozco como "seleccionador de lugares", pero no encuentro nada de información sobre cómo hacerlo o si ya hay formas sencillas de hacerlo. Tampoco sé si la forma en que lo busco es correcto.

Comment: Tal y como está planteada la pregunta yo apostaría a que se acabaría cerrardo como demasiado amplia o basada en opiniones. Quizá añadiendo más detalles - con que lenguaje lo quieres hacer, información que hayas podido encontrar, alguna prueba que hayas hecho aunque no lograras nada - tendría más posibilidades, aún así es posible que siga siendo demasiado amplia.

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene dos partes. La primera que es hasta la imagen me parece concreta y que se puede preguntar en el sitio si se le brinda mayor detalle. Concuerdo con @blonfu sobre la segunda parte: *¿Cómo se puede realizar?* ya lleva a una pregunta más amplia. Al menos te comento mi perspectiva: yo he visto este tipo de cosas como "distribución de asientos" desde aplicaciones de consola hechas en C, dispositivos móviles nativos (Android y iOS), aplicaciones Web, etc. Siendo así, preguntar *cómo se puede realizar* tiene **muchísimas** respuestas.

Comment: Ante una pregunta de este tipo, sugiero que el primer recurso al que puedes acceder es al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde este tipo de preguntas *rápidas* (al menos para la primer parte que comenta Luiggi) son bien recibidas. Posteriormente, ya que tengas un contexto más amplio y te surjan dudas puntuales, ahora sí las puedas hacer sobre el sitio principal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aportando a los comentarios de Blonfu y Luiggi, descompongamos tu pregunta en pedazos...

La primera, como se llama esto, es valida. No es sobre código (o sea, por ese punto no seria valida), pero bien podría ser un componente particular de una librería en un lenguaje particular.

Por lo tanto, si vos me decís que viste ese mismo componente en 3 apps distintas de un teléfono, sobre android y iphone, exactamente iguales, entonces se podría inferir que es un control genérico de alguna librería. Que no quiere decir que exista, tal vez lo hizo todo la misma empresa ;).

La segunda parte.. de como lo puedo hacer.. cae en el problema de ser basada en opiniones... Imagínate que aunque me digas, como lo puedo hacer en X tecnología.. seguro alguno te dirá que uses una matriz.. otro el framework P, otro una base de datos y miles de objetos.. y así.. y en realidad lo que tienes es una lista de recomendaciones.. donde cualquier opción es valida.. Por lo tanto, salvo que restrinjas mucho la pregunta, y pegues secciones de código, el como lo puedo hacer.. es muy amplio...

Comment: Yo añadiría que la segunda pregunta se puede hacer buena intentando él mismo hacerlo. Una vez se atasque pone una pregunta con lo que intenta conseguir (la foto), con el código que tiene y con el problema que le atasca. Por lo demás, de acuerdo contigo.

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto a **si es válido preguntar cómo se llama algo**, mientras sea en el contexto de programación y ámbitos de los profesionales de informática, **sí lo es**.

La pregunta mostrada como ejemplo, seguramente, por ser breve, no sería una buena pregunta por las razones siguientes, entre otras:

1. Consta de varias preguntas. Cada publicación de tipo pregunta debe incluir una sola pregunta y si bien el español permite el uso de preguntas como elementos retóricos, lo que he visto es que eso podría atraer respuestas puntuales para cada un de las preguntas y eso no es deseable.
2. No se incluye contexto de donde fue encontrado el elemento por cuyo nombre se pregunta, tampoco se indica la perspectiva desde la cual preguntas, aunque se podría inferir por las otras preguntas, sin embargo, si las eliminas para evitar que la pregunta sea demasiado amplia, el enfoque quedaría del todo incierto.